# Access App.Config File from a C# Assembly called by an executable

Tags: c#

Is it possible to access an App.Config File from a C# Class Library that is called from an exe?

We are running into error's and getting null when we try access the config file? I presume its to do with the originator of the call on the library, is there a work around to this other than hard coding to the file system in the Class Library?

```
       try
        {
            string cleanupScripts = string.Empty;
            cleanupScripts = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CleanupScripts"];

            if (cleanupScripts == null)
            {
                throw new System.ApplicationException("Null was returned");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw (ex); 

        }
```

Cheers

Comment: Can you show us the relevant config file, and the code you use to access it??  You should be using the standard .NET objects and method from `System.Configuration` and there should be no problem at all to do this, really....

Comment: ... and can you show us what error you are running into?

Comment: Update to this post and thanks for the feedback, the application calling the Class Library is a Ruby command line that passes in scalar variables to the C# Library, inside the library we wont to read config data (connection string etc which the calling application will know nothing about). It's a design requirement we can not change. I will get the error from my Dev Team, ps we are using System.Configuration

Comment: Code above, I just replicated my self by calling a class library from a C# Console App with a project reference

Comment: Do you try this : `var appConfig = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location); string CleanupScripts = appConfig.AppSettings.Settings["CleanupScripts"].Value;`

Comment: I did JPBlanc, reflection used the path of the calling application to look for the config file not the Class Library it called, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if you can do this, but I am pretty sure that C# Class Libraries allow you to use Resources.
I think its probably best for you to store the App.Config as a Resource and then access you App.config from the Resource.

But I guess the question is, why are you storing Configuration items inside a DLL? why don't you create constructors on your library and have your configuration in the UI that is calling your C# Class library.

Comment: Hey Robbie, I think I will go with this approach, but just set the stringa (key value pairs) as resources and then access them from the code using the <projectName>.Properties etc...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When reading app config values from a class library function, it is the app.config of the exe that is read. The general idea is that each client using a library should supply the relevant configuration itself. So if you have an app.config in your class library project, that one will never be read.

Answer (score 0):

when deployed app.config files are copied as ProjectName.exe.config. You should be reading this file from the class library.

Hope that I understood the question correctly

Thanks
Goku

Comment: I can see the ProjectName.exe.config in the bin\debug directory but it still returns null, am I meant to tell ConfigurationManager.AppSettings to look somewhere else or use another access operator?

Answer (score 0):

It's easy :

First you go in the properties of your C# project

[image]

Then to the paraméters tab

[image]

Then you click to create parameters, you choose a name, a type, value, scope

[image]

It creates an XML file name `YourEXEFile.config` in the `bin` folder. Then you can use it in your code. Or you can modify it outside your code.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  string myP = Properties.Settings.Default.myParam1;

  Console.WriteLine(myP);
}
```

You can modify it in your project :

[image]

Comment: Stupid question, how do I access the parameters section in the properties, when I go to the properties of the project all I can see is Application, Build, etc... right down to Signing. I really like this approach if I can find it :)

Comment: What kind of Visual Studio project are you using ?

Comment: Sorry, Class Library in Visual Studio 2010

Comment: So, right click on the project itself and click on properties. On the left panel you'll see a tab parameters. Then click on the URL on the middle panel.

Comment: When I right click on the project all I see is these tabs down the left hand side? (Application, Build, Build Events, Debug, Resources, Services, Settings, Reference Paths, Signing)

Comment: Thanks but I am right clicking in the correct place and still don't see the parameters, have you changed your VS in some way to add this, its not their by default on mine and this is a clean install?

Comment: Can you give a hard copy of your application tab

Comment: Forgive me, you say hard copy you mean screendump on here? Not sure how to get the pic...

Comment: I will have to look into this further, really like this approach.